# Why is $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2+1)$ not a field if $p \equiv 1 \bmod4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

here I am again with another question.

*Assume that p is prime, and $ \ p \equiv 1\bmod4$.
 Prove that $\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2+1)$ is not a field.*

I don't know how to tackle this problem. First I'll show you what I observed myself.

We know the definiton $\mathbb{F}_p := \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. This is a field. I don´t know if $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ is a field, because I don't know if every polynomial has an inverse polynomial.

For proving the claim, it is enough to find a pair of non-trivial elements $a, b$ so that $a \cdot b = 0$, or a non-trivial element that cannot be inversed. But I failed to do so.

I could make use of a theorem as well: for every homomorphism $\phi: R \rightarrow S$, the following holds:
$$ R/\ker (\phi) \cong \phi(R)$$
By defining $\phi: \ \mathbb{F}_p[X] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[i] \ 
: \ \sum_j \bar{a_j}X^j  \mapsto \sum_j \bar{a_j}i^j$ This mapping is surjective because 
$a+bX \mapsto a+bi$, and $(X^2+1) \subseteq \ker(\phi)$, but I don't know how to determine if the image is actually a field.

The last things I share with you is that $\mathbb{F_p}^* \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$, and that $i^p = i^{4k+1}=1$. I have the feeling that I somehow should make use of this, but I don't know how.

Thank you for reading this. I am looking forward to your reactions.

Comment: If $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: You have reached the key point in the last paragraph. If $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ then $g^{(p-1)/4}$ is of order 4, i.e. can serve in the role of $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: $R[X]$ is never a field. Also if $R$ is a field and $I$ is an ideal of $R$, then either $I=(0)$ or $I=R$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod  4$, then the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ is not irreducible in $F_p[x]$. One way of seeing this is to use the theory of quadratic residue. The quadratic residue formula is $\binom{a}{p} = a^\frac{p - 1}{2}$. If $\binom{a}{p} = 1$, then $x^2 - a$ has a solution in $F_p$.

It is well known that for any commutative ring $R$ with $1$ and ideal $I$, $R/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is maximal. In the context of polynomial rings, it amounts to the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ being irreducible.